# Django - Get all posts that were created in a month in a certain timezone

Tags: python, django

So I have this `Post` model, which is like a wall post on Facebook or Reddit. I want to be able to retrieve all posts that were `created` in a month under a certain time zone. The reason for this is because I have a paginator on my app that let's the users see posts by month and I want to query for it rather than send them all the posts as it could be thousands and that'll take a long time(I plan on paginating the per month post retrieval as well). I also want it in their time zone, because Django stores `datetime` in UTC so what could be a post created at the end of November in UTC should actually be in December when converted to the requestors local device time.

`model.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=POST_MAX_LEN)
```

So for example if a user creates 10 posts in November, 2 in December PST. Then I have a view that takes `month` and `time_zone` then it should return the 10 posts from November when given '11' for `month` and 'PST' for `time_zone`. **How do I return all posts from a month in a given time zone?**

**Setup:**

- Django 3.2.9
- Postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql doesn't store timezone on date neither timestamps, [quoting docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-datetime.html):

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

Then, you don't have enough info to make your query.

If you need to query by timezone, you should to create a new field on `Post` to store it.

Comment: sorry I think you misunderstand the question. I'll add more detail

Comment: I understood the question properly. Now, it is a different question. Quoting your original q: _Then I have a view that takes month and time_zone then it should return the 10 posts from November when given '11' for month and 'PST' for time_zone._

Comment: I rolled back to original Q. For a new question just create a new post. You should don't edit your question to change semantics.